# Error converting data type nvarchar to int using stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures

I know this is a fairly common error but I cannot seem to find the source to my problem. I am trying to add a student's details using a stored procedure due to having to enter data into two different tables but I am getting this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Error converting data type nvarchar to int.

on `myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

**ASP.NET**:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="courselist" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>' 
     SelectCommand="SELECT [course_name], [course_id] FROM [courses]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="yearlist" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>' 
     SelectCommand="SELECT [year_id], [year_title] FROM [year]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="advisor_tutor_list" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>'  
     SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT staff_records.f_name + ' ' + staff_records.l_name AS Name, staff_records.user_id FROM courses INNER JOIN staff_records ON courses.school = staff_records.school_id WHERE (courses.course_id = @course_id)">
     <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="course_id"></asp:Parameter>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="status_list" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>' 
     SelectCommand="SELECT [status_id], [status] FROM [status]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="current_academic_year" runat="server"  
     ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>' 
     SelectCommand="SELECT [academic_year] FROM [academic_year]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h1>Add Student Record</h1>
        <h5 class="subheading">Please use the form below to add a student:</h5>
        <div class="feedback blue" id="feedback" runat="server" visible="false">
            <asp:Label ID="feedback_text" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <img id="img_preview" src="images/default_profile.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
        <div class="panel">
            <h3>Fill out Student Details:</h3>
            <h5>Profile Image:</h5>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="newimage" runat="server" onpropertychange="changeImg(this.value)" />
            <h5>First Name:</h5>
            <asp:TextBox CssClass="full-width" ID="f_nametext" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <h5>Last Name:</h5>
            <asp:TextBox CssClass="full-width" ID="l_nametext" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <h5>Password:</h5>
            <asp:TextBox ID="p_wordtext" CssClass="inline-button" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <div class="button blue" id="generate_password_button">Create Password</div>
            <h5>Course:</h5>
            <asp:DropDownList CssClass="full-width" ID="courseddl" runat="server" DataSourceID="courselist" DataTextField="course_name" DataValueField="course_id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="courseddl_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" OnDataBound="courseddl_DataBound"></asp:DropDownList>
            <h5>Year:</h5>
            <asp:DropDownList CssClass="full-width" ID="yearddl" runat="server" DataSourceID="yearlist" DataTextField="year_title" DataValueField="year_id"></asp:DropDownList>
            <h5>Date of Birth:</h5>
            <asp:TextBox ID="dob_calendar" CssClass="datepicker full-width" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <h5>Part Time / Full Time Status:</h5>
            <asp:DropDownList CssClass="full-width" ID="enrolmentddl" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>Full Time</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Part Time</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <h5>Personal Tutor:</h5>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="tutorddl" CssClass="full-width" runat="server" DataSourceID="advisor_tutor_list" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="user_id"></asp:DropDownList>
            <h5>Advisor of Studies:</h5>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="advisorddl" CssClass="full-width" runat="server" DataSourceID="advisor_tutor_list" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="user_id"></asp:DropDownList>
            <h5>Enrollment Status:</h5>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="statusddl" CssClass="full-width" runat="server" DataSourceID="status_list" DataTextField="status" DataValueField="status_id"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="academic_year_ddl" CssClass="full-width" runat="server" DataSourceID="current_academic_year" DataTextField="academic_year" DataValueField="academic_year" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:Button ID="updatebutton1" runat="server" Text="Add Student" OnClick="updatebutton1_Click" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

C# code-behind:

```
protected void courseddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string course_id = courseddl.SelectedValue;
    advisor_tutor_list.SelectParameters["course_id"].DefaultValue = course_id;
    advisor_tutor_list.DataBind();
}

protected void courseddl_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    courseddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("- Select -", ""));
}

protected void updatebutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int newRand;
    newRand = rand.Next(1, 99);

    Random hashrand = new Random();
    int newhashrand;
    newhashrand = hashrand.Next(1000000000, int.MaxValue);

    string f_name_data = f_nametext.Text;
    string l_name_data = l_nametext.Text;
    string pword_data = p_wordtext.Text;

    string email_domain = "@uni.ac.uk";
    string role = "5";

    courseddl.DataBind();

    string course_data = courseddl.SelectedValue;
    string year_data = yearddl.SelectedValue;
    string enrolment_data = enrolmentddl.SelectedValue;
    string tutor_data = tutorddl.SelectedValue;
    string advisor_data = advisorddl.SelectedValue;
    string status_data = statusddl.SelectedValue;

    academic_year_ddl.DataBind();

    string academic_year = academic_year_ddl.SelectedValue;
    string dob_text = dob_calendar.Text;

    //check user has uploaded a file and filled in all fields
    if (!newimage.HasFile || f_name_data == "" || l_name_data == "" || dob_text == "" || pword_data == "") {
        feedback.Visible = true;
        feedback_text.Text = "Please ensure you've uploaded an image and filled out all fields. ";
        return;
    }

    DateTime dob_data = Convert.ToDateTime(dob_text);
    string f_name_initial = f_nametext.Text.Substring(0, 1);

    string UpPath = Server.MapPath("~/images");
    string new_name = "";

    Random r = new Random();
    int rInt = r.Next(0, 10000);

    if (!Directory.Exists(UpPath)) {
       Directory.CreateDirectory(UpPath);
    } else {
       int imgSize = newimage.PostedFile.ContentLength;
       string imgName = newimage.FileName;
       new_name = rInt + imgName;
       string imgPath = "images/" + new_name;

       if (newimage.PostedFile.ContentLength > 1000000) {
          Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Alert", "alert('File is too big.')", false);
       } else {
          newimage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
       }
    }

    string ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

    myConnection.Open();

    string query = "Execute AddStudent @password, @email, @role_id, @reset_hash, @student_id, @f_name, @l_name, @course_id, @year, @dob, @parttime_fulltime, @personal_tutor_id, @advisor, @status_id, @academic_year, @profile_image";

    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", EncryptPassword(pword_data));
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", f_name_initial + l_name_data + newRand + email_domain);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role_id", role);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reset_hash", newhashrand);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_id", "");
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_name", f_name_data);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l_name", l_name_data);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course_id", course_data);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", year_data);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dob_data);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parttime_fulltime", enrolment_data);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personal_tutor_id", tutor_data);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@advisor", advisor_data);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status_id", status_data);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@academic_year", academic_year);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profile_image", new_name);

    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    myConnection.Close();

    Response.Redirect("studentrecords.aspx");
  }

  private string EncryptPassword(string password) {
     System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 sha = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();
     string hashed = System.Convert.ToBase64String(sha.ComputeHash(System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password)));
     return hashed.Length > 49 ? hashed.Substring(0, 49) : hashed;
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddStudent 
    @password nvarchar(50),
    @email nvarchar(50),
    @role_id int,
    @reset_hash nvarchar(50),
    @student_id int,
    @f_name nvarchar(50),
    @l_name nvarchar(50),
    @course_id int,
    @year int,
    @dob datetime,
    @parttime_fulltime nvarchar(50),
    @personal_tutor_id int,
    @advisor int,
    @status_id int,
    @academic_year int,
    @profile_image nvarchar(max)
AS
    INSERT INTO users (password, email, role_id, reset_hash)
    VALUES (@password, @email, @role_id, @reset_hash);

    SET @student_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO student_records (user_id, f_name, l_name, course_id, year, dob, parttime_fulltime, personal_tutor_id, advisor, status_id, academic_year, profile_image)
    VALUES (@student_id, @f_name, @l_name, @course_id, @year, @dob, @parttime_fulltime, @personal_tutor_id, @advisor, @status_id, @academic_year, @profile_image)
```

`Users` table structure:

```
user_id int
password    nvarchar(50)    
email   nvarchar(50)    
role_id int 
reset_hash  nvarchar(50)
```

`student_records` table structure:

```
user_id int
f_name  nvarchar(50)    
l_name  nvarchar(50)    
course_id   int 
year    int
dob datetime
parttime_fulltime   nvarchar(50)    
profile_image   nvarchar(MAX)   
personal_tutor_id   int 
status_id   int 
academic_year   int 
home_email  nvarchar(256)   
advisor int
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the table structure for `users` and `student_records`?

Comment: @AdamV I updated my answer with the table structure's

Comment: Have you checked what the values each of the parameters are before you call ExecuteNonQuery? You are using string for all of them, and several are reading SelectedValue which could be an empty string or something that doesn't become an int. Step through your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

`myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_id", 0);`

Double check all these properties, you should not pass none integer values to them

```
@role_id int
@student_id int
@course_id int
@year int
@personal_tutor_id int
@advisor int
@status_id int
@academic_year int
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the below columns in your database table could be int, which suppose to be nvarchar

```
@email nvarchar(50),
@reset_hash nvarchar(50),
@f_name nvarchar(50),
@l_name nvarchar(50),
@parttime_fulltime nvarchar(50),
@profile_image nvarchar(max)
```

Comment: They are all nvarchar values in my Tables

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass Student_id like this

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_id", "");
```

You have to pass an int value instead.